# apply function in R won't concatenate row and column

Tags: r, apply

When I do this:

```
Matrix <-matrix(1:20, 4, 5)
```

and then this

```
B <- apply(Matrix, c(1,2), length)
```

when I print `B` I get a matrix of 1s instead 4 5s and 5 4s? Why please

Comment: Because `c(1, 2)` runs over the rows AND columns, so you get the length of each element

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to understand the `MARGIN` argument of the `apply` function.  Using `c(1,2)` applies the function to rows and columns (that is, to every value in the matrix). So of course you get an equal sized matrix filled with `1`. For rows only, use a `MARGIN` argument of `1` and for columns use `2`.

```
> apply(Matrix, 2, length)
[1] 4 4 4 4 4
> apply(Matrix, 1, length)
[1] 5 5 5 5
```